# Basic CSS styles not applying

Tags: css, image, button, squarespace

I cannot figure out how to get some basic CSS styles to apply to my blog. I'm trying to customize my blog summary page. I want the "read more" button centered and for the picture to show correctly. For some reason the picture keeps moving and it cuts it half off. I've tried multiple things to different classes and nothing works. It was originally on the left with the text to the right of the thumbnail and I'm moving the picture above the text if that means anything.

I've tried text align center for the button in multiple divs and it doesn't budge. Can anyone help? I can only adjust CSS not HTML on my Squarespace site, and the limited styles they give you doesn't allow me to adjust any of this. I'm not a coder, I just kinda understand it enough, so any help is appreciated.

Here is the page: https://www.themodernrenovator.com/blog

Here is custom CSS I added to make the button a circle, but can't get it to center:

```
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 12px !important;
  background-color: #f0ede9;
  margin: auto;
}
.view-list article .excerpt-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
}

.view-list article .excerpt-thumb .intrinsic .content {
  position: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.intrinsic {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.entry-title {
  text-align: center;
}
.article-dateline {
  text-align: center;
}
article .post span.inline-action {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.article-meta {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you remove that CSS that you've added and reload the page as you normally would, does the issue persist? That will confirm whether the issue is caused by the CSS you have added. I'd recommend updating your question based on what you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend centering the "READ MORE" button using the following CSS, inserted via the [CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor):

```
article .post span.inline-action {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The "cut off" image problem, on the other hand, should not be corrected with CSS because it is an issue with Squarespace's ImageLoader function. To correct it, add the following via [global Footer code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection). If code injection is not available to you, insert the code via a [Markdown block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813788-Markdown-Blocks) in the footer of your website.

```
<script>
// Fix Squarespace ImageLoader Bug.
function fixImages() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');
  var i = images.length;
  while (i--) {
    ImageLoader.load(images[i], {load: true});
  }
}
fixImages();
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  fixImages();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the premium account right now. Was trying to keep this one as personal but may have to upgrade. That fixed the button center problem though!

Comment: Actually took off body text-align center and it made the button not be centered again

Comment: I updated the answer to mention that the code can also be added via a markdown block in the footer. Regarding the button centering, it's unclear to me what you meant. Perhaps removing your own CSS and custom formatting, then posting back would allow others to make suggestions that do not conflict with your own customizations. Or, update your original question to include the applicable CSS you've added.

Comment: I added the custom CSS I added to it, so not sure if something else I did affected the button being able to be centered. Also can't get the article dateline to be center.

Comment: Ahh finally got it figured out! Your script worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your images are cut off because you have a `top:` value that's currently set to -300px. I can't tell where it's being affected just by looking at this, but somewhere in your styling you have the child img of your `excerpt-image` getting a top value being set.

[image]

To center your 'read more' link: `.inline-read-more { margin: auto; }`

Comment: Yeah I saw that top value and couldn't figure out why that was happening. The image was a square thumbnail on the left originally, so I don't know if what I added to the CSS is affecting the position. This is what I added: 
    `.view-list article .excerpt-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.element-style {
  position: inherit;
}
.view-list article .excerpt-thumb .intrinsic .content {
  position: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.intrinsic {
  padding: 0px !important;
}`